# Linker errors while integrating Google APIs Objective-C Client Library

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gdata, google-api-objc-client

I am trying to integrate Google APIs Objective-C Client Library in my application, I follow the guide given [in this link](http://techxposed.blogspot.com/2012/09/google-objective-c-client-api-xcode.html). but now the problem is it is giving me 8 errors. And i am unable to understand where the problem is. Can any one guide me where the problem is, I am using xcode 4.6

[image: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLCollectionObject", referenced from:]

Comment: Please see comment section in the link you have posted. There are few steps missing.

Comment: yes, i had also follow those steps

Comment: and i had also delete the _Sources.m file

Comment: have you tried to run it on device? Might be your .a file is generated for device only. You can check architecure for what this file is generated.

Comment: @Iducool you know man you are genius, can you tell me why it is not working on simulator

Comment: can you tell me what should i set for architecture to make it work on simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually You have compiled that static library for Device only. To compile it for Simulator just select the "iPhone 6.x Simulator" or any whatever simulator version you have available in GTL.xcodeproject and compile that project. And follow that same process that is mentioned in tutorial.

After you have compiled and build, goto Organiser->Projects->GTL and click on the little arrow for Derived  Data.

You will find libGTLTouchStaticLib.a file and Headers folder in derived data's project folder->Build->Products->Debug-iphonesimulator

First rename that static library because you have already added static library for device with the same name after that drag that file into your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in project target build setting headers and frameworks search path to google API folder path.

Comment: i added "$(SRCROOT)/../libGTLTouchStaticLib.a" in framework search path and also the header path too in header path, but same errors

Comment: because i had copy those file just outside of my project folder